# Fragment vs Service for a Bluetooth connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am learning about Android and I want to make an application that connects through Bluetooth, I would like to have at least 3 screens in my application that share the bluetooth connection, at this moment I have the code that shows the devices and that makes the connection , but I don't know how to pass that bluetooth connection between all the screens. I have been searching and basically reading about 2 solutions, one is to make a service for all the bluetooth code and the second is to use snippets, I really don't know what is the best or the simplest solution for my problem, Does anyone have any advice on this problem? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Application object to store the Bluetooth connection in an object and using your Activities to get it?

Try something like this. (Note: I have never worked with Bluetooth on Android, so I don't know which relevant classes to use. In this case, I'll use **BluetoothDevice**, since it seems to be the right class based on the library documentation)

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
    BluetoothDevice device;
    ...
    public synchronized BluetoothDevice getBtConnection() {
        if (device == null) {
            // construct a BluetoothDevice object and put it into variable device
        }
        return device;
    }
}
```

That way, your first activity just has to do this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
private BluetoothDevice device;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super(b);
    ...
    device = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getBtDevice();
    ...
}
...
```

}

And then, any time your other Activities need to use that connection, they just need to call **getBtDevice()**, because **FirstActivity** already instantiated it.

I hope you requirement are full fill.
Thank you